# Enthalpy of formaton

Tags: thermodynamics, synthesis, energy, heat, enthalpy

today I was doing a set of HW problems regarding enthalpy and stumble upon one problem that I found confusing.It was the standard enthalpy of formation for CaCO3 is -1207.6 kJ mol when 30.7 g of calcium is reacted with an excess of carbon dioxide, how much heat is transferred?
So I was wondering if the reaction was exothermic or endothermic. For my answer, I said it was exothermic because the standard enthalpy of formation had a negative value which indicates it released heat and it evolved 370.4 kJ of heat. So I was wondering if my answer was correct? Any help would be appreciated.I am a bit lost for this unit cause I was sick for most of the thermodynamics unit.

Comment: Come on everybody, downvotes with no comments for someone with 1 rep? Daniel, I suspect the downvotes are because SE isn't intended to be a replacement for your classmates, teacher, TAs, or textbook, all of whom would be a better reference if you missed class. If you're still unsure after consulting those sources, please edit the question to explain why you don't understand how the standard rules laid out there apply to this specific problem.

Comment: Also, please check out the tour if you haven't yet: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @Erick people don't or forget to comment. That's why we have you, or anyone else who's willing to comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct.

If it helps, you could visualise the internal energy of the system: If the enthalpy change is negative, then the internal energy of the system is decreasing and so energy is being released as heat; as we know this is an exothermic enthalpy change. Vice versa for an endothermic enthalpy change.